# Using placeholder instead of label

Tags: html, label, accessibility, screen-readers

When it comes to accessibility, it's a common practice to not use placeholders as substitute for labels because upon entering something into the field, the placeholder disappears. But what if my placeholder acts as a visual label afterwards?

[image: Before focus and entry]

[image: After focus and entry]

Is it still okay to only use a placeholder in this case in place of an actual Label? If so, do I also need to tag it with an aria-label as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not recommend using a `placeholder` attribute or other container in place of a `<label>` element.

This is not an issue of having a "visual label", as you described. The `<label>` element is associated with the `<input>` element programmatically at the data-level.

```
<label for="middle-initial">Middle Initial</label>
<input id="middle-initial">
```

The `placeholder` attribute is essentially invisible to screen readers, so it can be used in conjunction with `<label>`, however it should not be used as a substitute for a `<label>`.

If you really don't like the visual appearance of having the `<label>` on your page, you can [position the text off screen using CSS](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/), or if you're currently using bootstrap, you can use the `.sr-only` class.

Comment: One can add the invisible aria-label tag on their inputs for screen readers to read. In WebStorm, for example, this removes the warning that would otherwise appear and say that a label is required.

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs - You could maybe get away with this, depending on who is reviewing or approving your work, but it's still unquestionably better to use a real `label`.  Using `aria-label` means that you'll also need a visual label for sighted users. This opens the door for the two labels to become out of sync if one gets updated and the other doesn't.  Also, remember the First Rule of ARIA: https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#firstrule